# Installing azure devops extension in powershell but getting error

Tags: powershell, azure-devops, scripting, ssl-certificate, devops

I am trying to install an azure DevOps extension in PowerShell using the command:
az extension add --name azure-devops
. But, getting certification error.
I tried to generate a selfsigned cert and tried to ping the url mentioned in error, was able to ping the url but error remain still there. The error is as below:
Please ensure you have network connection. Error detail:
HTTPSConnectionPool(host='objects.githubusercontent.com', port=443): Max retries exceeded with url: /github-production-release-asset-2e65be/107708057/8c8c37f1-25aa-4394-9b37-ab8655c6d437?X-Amz-Algorithm=AWS4-HMAC-SHA256&X-Amz-Credential=AKIAIWNJYAX4CSVEH53A%2F20230210%2Fus-east-1%2Fs3%2Faws4_request&X-Amz-Date=20230210T092547Z&X-Amz-Expires=300&X-Amz-Signature=e65868999583f165ce08abf46e4e192fccffcd611847d2da76c25473f27927a4&X-Amz-SignedHeaders=host&actor_id=0&key_id=0&repo_id=107708057&response-content-disposition=attachment%3B%20filename%3Dazure_devops-0.26.0-py2.py3-none-any.whl&response-content-type=application%2Foctet-stream (Caused by SSLError(SSLCertVerificationError(1, '[SSL: CERTIFICATE_VERIFY_FAILED] certificate verify failed: self signed certificate in certificate chain (_ssl.c:997)')))

I tried generating the selfsign certificate. Tried to install on current userscope.Also, tried to ping the url mentioned in error and it was giving reply back[image]

Comment: I have managed to solve the error by simply disabling the proxy form my pc. The error was happening due to bad handshake i.e due to proxy vpn.

Answer (score 0):

Adding the following environment variable:

```
export AZURE_CLI_DISABLE_CONNECTION_VERIFICATION=1
```

worked for me